# UIActivityViewController not Sharing both Text and Image on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, share, socialshare, swift4.1

I used the UIActivityViewController to sharing both Image and Text. In other apps like twitter, notes, email have all worked. In facebook it does not have text and have only image to share. Please help me how to share both Image and Text to work with Facebook and UIActivityViewController.

Here is my code :

```
    // Screenshot the Result Page

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)

    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    // Prepare to share.

    let text = "Let`s start to play Kanji Quiz. Improve your Kanji skills."

    let shareAll = [text , image!] as [Any]

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.message, UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"), UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"), UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.markupAsPDF ]

    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: no , you can't do this ,

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to prefill text. The user needs to write it

Comment: awwww... Thank you very much. #Anbu.karthik and #WizKid